# How to pass values to python from a jQueryMobile Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, slider, cgi

I'm trying to set up a web page with a jQuery Mobile slider that passess the values of the slider to a python script. Ultimate goal is to use this slider to control a python script via the website which runs a motor connected to Arduino. The slider should control the speed of the motor.

I'm adapting the code from [Running Python CGI Scripts from Javascript and JQuery Mobile UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996414/running-python-cgi-scripts-from-javascript-and-jquery-mobile-ui) but I can't really get it to work.

Here's my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Slider Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js">    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.posting-slider').on('slidestop', function(e) {
            $.post('cgi-bin/script.py', { id: $(this).data('slider-id'), value: e.target.value }, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log('POSTed: ' + textStatus);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <div class="rgbw_label">
                <label for="red_slider">
                Slider 1:
                </label>
            </div>
            <input type="range" id="slider1" name="slider1" class="posting-slider" data-slider-id="1" value="0" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div> 
</div>
```

And here's my script.py (in a cgi-bin folder).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cgi
form=cgi.FieldStorage()

import json

#Real code I will be running, haven't tested it yet
#import serial
#ser = serial.Serial('dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
#ser.write("%s\n" % (form["value"]))
#ser.close()

#Testing code
file=open('test.txt', "w")
file.write("HELLO")
file.close()

print "Content-type: application/json"
print
print(json.JSONEncoder().encode({"status":"ok"}))
```

I'm running it on raspberry pi with an apache2 server.

The web page is loading up with the slider as expected. Also when I go to localhost/cgi-bin/script.py the script is run and the test.txt file is generated.

The problem seems to be with the javascript, it's not triggering the script.py file to run and I don't know if it's passing values correctly.

Can anyone see a problem? Thanks!

Comment: refrain from using `.ready()` in jQM.

Comment: Why is that? How would I write it instead?

Comment: Bind it to JQM events. http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using a jQuery version that is too old. When debugging this, I saw that the slider element you had selected didn't have an 'on' method. When I tried the same example with jquery 1.9.1, it worked fine.

Check it out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Slider Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var slider = $('#slider1');
            $('#slider1').on('slidestop', function(e) {
            $.post('cgi-bin/script.py', { id: $(this).data('slider-id'), value: e.target.value }, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log('POSTed: ' + textStatus);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <div class="rgbw_label">
                <label for="red_slider">
                Slider 1:
                </label>
            </div>
            <input type="range" id="slider1" name="slider1" class="posting-slider" data-slider-id="1" value="0" min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true" />
            <!-- <input type="range" name="slider-1" id="slider-1" value="60" min="0" max="100" /> -->
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant, it was the version numbers. jquery 1.9.1 worked, but seemed to mess up the style of the slider so I'm using 1.8.2, so the exact same setup as http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-mobile/getting-started/. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, it can be confusing to look through so many resources online referencing so many different jquery versions/combinations. Chrome debugger is key to keeping your sanity.

Best of luck, sounds like a sweet project